# How to succesfully build a project using the MSBuild?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I have a 3-dr party project that I'd like to build. The author said to build it I have to use the `MSBuild`. Here is the exact citation from him:

> - Clone https://github.com/NovaRain/DXSDK_Collection.git to some
> - Copy \DXSDK_Aug2007\Lib\x86\dinput.lib to \DXSDK_Jun2010\Lib\x86\
> - Set environment variable DXSDK_DIR to "\DXSDK_Jun2010" (trailing slash is important)
> - In sfall directory (where ddraw.sln is), create empty PostBuild.cmd
> - Run VS installer and add "MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)" if you don't have it already
> - Find MSBuild.exe and run: `MSBuild.exe path\to\ddraw.sln -p:Configuration=ReleaseXP -p:Platform=Win32 -p:PlatformToolset=v140_xp`

I've followed all the steps carefully but when i run the `MSBuild` command I'm getting followin error: "`Cannot open include file: 'algorithm': No such file or directory`"

here is the *stdafx.h* header content for a reference:

```
#pragma once
#pragma message("Compiling precompiled headers.\n")

#define WINVER       _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP

#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <string>

//#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define NOCRYPT
#define NOSERVICE
#define NOMCX
#define NOIME
#include <Windows.h>

#include <intrin.h>
```

How could it be that the `Standard Library` headers isn't available  since I've done a standard VS c++ installation?

Comment: Make sure you run `msbuild` at a [developer cmd prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160#developer_command_prompt_shortcuts).